# A select component in a wrapper component does not change its placeholder but value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a select component that doesn't change it's placeholder when I'm clicking its options. It's wrapped around on another component that serves as the outline of like its title. paragraph and then the select component. I also use it on another select component and it also doesn't work. I am pretty sure it changes it value since I checked the state and also the functionality works excpect the changing of the so called placeholder. This is the original outline which works.

```
<div className={`flex flex-col col-span-6`}>
        <div className="flex items-center mb-1">
            <h2 className='text-sm'>TYPE OF FLIGHT ANF REGION</h2>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGlobe} className="text-[#2B8E9B] ml-2" />
        </div>
        <p className='text-xs mb-3'>Choose a type of flight, either DOMESTIC or INTERNATIONAL, and pick which region your coming.</p>
        <div className={`grid grid-cols-2 gap-4`}>
            <FlightTypeComponent flights={domestic} flightLocalType={"domestic"} {...{flightType, locationsFilter, flightTypeClick ,regionSetter}}/>
            <FlightTypeComponent flights={international} flightLocalType={"international"} {...{flightType, locationsFilter, flightTypeClick ,regionSetter}}/>
        </div></div>
```

This is the current outline which doesn't work:

```
<TwoComponents title={"TYPE OF FLIGHT ANF REGION"} icon={faGlobe} colSpan={"col-span-6"} childrenCss={"grid-cols-2"} paragraph={"Choose a type of flight, either DOMESTIC or INTERNATIONAL, and pick which region your coming."}>
        <FlightTypeComponent flights={domestic} flightLocalType={"domestic"} {...{flightType, locationsFilter, flightTypeClick ,regionSetter}}/>
        <FlightTypeComponent flights={international} flightLocalType={"international"} {...{flightType, locationsFilter, flightTypeClick ,regionSetter}}/>
      </TwoComponents>
```

The wrapper in question. I both included both components even if I only showcased the TwoComponents incase of any errors or bad practices.

```
const EachComponentOutline = () => {
const TwoComponents = ({children, title, paragraph, icon, colSpan, childrenCss}) => {
return (
    <div className={`flex flex-col ${colSpan}`}>
        <div className="flex items-center mb-1">
            <h2 className='text-sm'>{title}</h2>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} className="text-[#2B8E9B] ml-2" />
        </div>
        <p className='text-xs mb-3'>{paragraph}</p>
        <div className={`grid ${childrenCss} gap-4`}>
            {children}
        </div>
    </div>

)}

const OneComponent = ({children, title, icon, paragraph, colSpan}) => 
(
    <div className={`flex flex-col ${colSpan}`}>
        {icon ? (
            <div className="flex mb-1">
                <h2 className='text-sm'>{title}</h2>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} className="text-[#2B8E9B] ml-2" />
            </div>
            ) 
            : (<h2 className='text-sm mb-1'>{title}</h2>)
        }
        <p className="text-xs mb-3">{paragraph}</p>
        {children}
      </div>
)
return {TwoComponents, OneComponent}
```

}

picture of the placeholder since I'm not sure if "placeholder" is the right term

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I answered it but I don't know why and I hope someone can better explain it. Instead of trying to create two components on a single function. You create each component in its own separate function so basically like removing the overall parent function for both TwoComponent and OneComponent. I think using a custom hook would return data and not a whole component so it's better to export and import it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).